# Query to add multiple data in single row into mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to add multiple data for a single row.i.e to add privileges to the registered person.The Privileges are code,admin,user,audit.I am able to create a single privilege to the person but the need is to add multiple privilege because the person with user privilege should also have audit privilege.

What I have done is, Registering a person with the single privillege and fetching their information from session and I use until the session is closed. I works perfectly. But what I need is to create multiple privilege. Please help me with php coding and mysql query. I am really new to php and mysql(for Programming)

---

Here is the Html form for the registration I have created.

```
<form class="form-inline"enctype="multipart/form-data" action="add.php" method="POST">
   <div class="form-group">  
   <label class="sr-only" for="Employee name">Employee name</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="employee name" placeholder="Enter Employee Name" name="empname">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">  
   <label class="sr-only" for="Employee name">Employee ID</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="employee id" placeholder="Enter Employee ID" name="empid">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">  
   <label class="sr-only" for="Employee password">Employee Password</label>
   <input type="password" class="form-control" id="employee name" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">  
   <label class="sr-only" for="Employee name">Confirm password</label>
   <input type="password" class="form-control" id="confirm password" placeholder="Re-Enter Password" name="repassword">
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">  
   <label class="sr-only" for="Employee Photo">Employee Photo</label>
   <input type="file" class="form-control" id="employee photo" placeholder="Upload Employee photo" name="photo" value="upload image">
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">  
   <label for="privilege">privilege</label>
   <select name="privilege" class="form-control">
   <option value="Admin">Admin</option>
   <option value="Super Admin">Super Admin</option>
   <option value="HR">HR</option>
   <option value="Manager">Manager</option>
   <option value="Client">Client</option>
    <option value="Audit">Audit</option>
     <option value="User">User</option>
      <option value="Coder">Coder</option>
      <option value="User & Audit">User and Audit</option>

   </select>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button></div>
     <div class="form-group">
    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary">Reset</button>
</div>
 <div class="form-group">
    <a href="home.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</button></a>
</div>

    </form>
```

add.php

```
<?php 

 //This is the directory where images will be saved 
 $target = "profiles/"; 
 $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']); 

 //This gets all the other information from the form 
 $empname=$_POST['empname']; 
 $empid=$_POST['empid']; 
 $pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']); 
 $password=$_POST['password']; 
 $repassword=$_POST['repassword']; 
 $privilege=$_POST['privilege'];


 // Connects to your Database 
 mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()) ; 
 mysql_select_db("records") or die(mysql_error()) ; 

 //Writes the information to the database 
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO `registration` VALUES ('$empname', '$empid', '$pic', '$password', '$repassword', '$privilege')") ; 

 //Writes the photo to the server 
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
 { 

 //Tells you if its all ok 
 echo "The file ".basename($_FILES['photo']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory"; 
 } 
 else { 

 //Gives and error if its not 
 echo "<p class='text-danger'>Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.</p>"; 
 echo "<a href='register.php'>Click here for registration</a>";
 } 
 ?>
```

> SQL:
>
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `registration` (   `empname` varchar(30)
>   NOT NULL,   `empid` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',   `photo`
>   varchar(30) NOT NULL,   `password` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
>   `repassword` varchar(30) NOT NULL,   `privilege` varchar(50) NOT NULL
>   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;`enter code here`

Comment: Please let me know is it possible or not.

Comment: created a table with the following columns(CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `registration` (
  `empname` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `empid` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `photo` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    `privilege` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: Without any code no one can help you.

Comment: can you place your code

Answer (score 0):

Here you work with this you will get....make your select field name array [] so that you can insert multiple values in single row

```
 <select name="privilege[]" class="form-control">
 <option value="Admin">Admin</option>
 <option value="Super Admin">Super Admin</option>
 <option value="HR">HR</option>
 <option value="Manager">Manager</option>
 <option value="Client">Client</option>
 <option value="Audit">Audit</option>
 <option value="User">User</option>
 <option value="Coder">Coder</option>
 <option value="User & Audit">User and Audit</option>

 </select>
```

While inserting just implode

```
$implode=implode(',',$_POST['privilege']);
```

Insert this $implode in the table field name